# Is there a way to get unweighted residuals and fitted values from a WLS regression in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm working on question C9 in Wooldridge's Intro to Econometrics Textbook. It asks you to obtain the *unweighted* fitted values and residuals from a weighted least squares regression. Does the following code give me the weighted or unweighted fitted values and residuals?

```
fitted(wlsmodel)
resid(wlsmodel)
```

I'm getting different answers from those in the textbook and I'm thinking it must be because the code I'm entering is giving me weighted fitted values and residuals. If this is the case, is there a way to get *unweighted* fitted values and residuals from a wls regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out.

Chapter 8, question C9
(i) Obtain the OLS estimates in equation (8.35)

```
library(wooldridge)    
reg<-lm(cigs~log(income)+log(cigpric)+educ+age+I(age^2)+restaurn,data=smoke)
```

(ii) Obtain the hhat used in the WLS estimation of equation (8.36) and reproduce equation (8.36). From this equation, obtain the unweighted residuals and fitted values; call these uhat and yhat, respectively.

```
uhat<-resid(reg)
uhat2<-uhat^2
ghat<-fitted(lm(log(uhat^2)~log(income)+log(cigpric)+educ+age+I(age^2)+restaurn,data=smoke))
hhat<-exp(ghat)
wls<-lm(cigs~log(income)+log(cigpric)+educ+age+I(age^2)+restaurn,weight=1/hhat,data=smoke)
uhatwls<-resid(wls)
yhatwls<-fitted(wls)
```

(iii) Let utilde=uhat/sqrt(hhat) and ytilde=yhat/sqrt(hhat) be the weighted quantities. Carry out the special case of the white test for heteroskedasticity by regressing utilde^2 on ytilde and ytilde^2, being sure to include an intercept, as always. Do you find heteroskedasticity in the weighted residuals?

```
utilde<-uhatwls/sqrt(hhat)
ytilde<-yhatwls/sqrt(hhat)
utilde2<-utilde^2
ytilde2<-ytilde^2
whitetest<-lm(utilde2~ytilde+ytilde2)
summary(whitetest)
Call:
lm(formula = utilde2 ~ ytilde + ytilde2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-5.579 -1.801 -1.306 -0.855 90.871 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.06146    0.96043  -0.064  0.94899   
ytilde       0.28667    1.41212   0.203  0.83918   
ytilde2      2.40597    0.78615   3.060  0.00228 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.414 on 804 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.027, Adjusted R-squared:  0.02458 
F-statistic: 11.15 on 2 and 804 DF,  p-value: 1.667e-05
```

The process above gives the correct answers as given in the solutions manual, so I know it has been done correctly. The thing that was confusing me was the request to obtain the 'unweighted' residuals from the WLS. It turns out that these are just the residuals obtained by default from that regression, which are then weighted in part (iii) of the question, as per above. The goal being to then test the WLS regression for heteroskedasticity, which is indeed present in the WLS regression.